# How to create auto disable select option?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have some problems about option select.

I want the select option auto disable if user didn't pick size t-shirt. And in total order the option select max order same with stock size t-shirt.

Exam :
Size S have a 15 stock
Size M have a 20 stock

And in the option select max order corresponding with stock of size t-shirt.
If user pick size s the option select order auto max number to 15, and user pick size m the option select order auto max number to 20.

[image]

And about the number stock get from database

I'm use codeigniter with bootstrap

This my code :
Select Option Size T-Shirt

```
<?php

$sprod = $stok['stok_s'];
$mprod = $stok['stok_m'];
$lprod = $stok['stok_l'];

if ($sprod == 0 && $mprod != 0 && $lprod != 0) {
    echo '<select name=produk_size id=produk_size class=form-control onchange=proses_stok() style=width:95%>
    <option value=0>Select Size:</option>
    <option value=stok_s disabled>s</option>
    <option value=stok_m>m</option>
    <option value=stok_l>L</option>
    </select>';
    ?>
```

Option Select Order Number

```
<select name="produk_stok" id="produk_stok" class="form-control" style="width:95%">
    <?php

    $stok_prod = $stok['stok_s'] + $stok['stok_m'] + $stok['stok_l'];

    if ($stok_prod == 0 )
    {
        echo "<option value=0> 0 </option>";
    }
    else{

        for($a=$stok['min_buy'];
            $a<=$stok['stok']; $a+=1)
        { 
          echo "<option value=$a>$a</option>";
      }
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function proses_stok(){
        var produk_stock = document.getElementById("produk_size").value;
        document.getElementById("produk_stock").value=produk_stock;
    }
</script>
```

And when I change the size the option select number didn't change. And when i'm select "select size" the option select number order didn't disable/just 0 stock

Comment: where is your code

Comment: Don't ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude

Comment: sorry im forgot to turn off :(

Comment: I still didn't get what you want to achieve here ..please can you elaborate ?

Comment: I want if user select size s and then the option select number max number is same with total stock s 1-15 stock option. and if user select size m the option select number with 1-20 option dropdown number

Comment: fyi, "size s" is disabled, so it cannot be selected. And, make sure you target the correct `id`s in your script, `getElementById("produk_stock")` vs `id="produk_stok"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for-loop` to make all options disabled from a particular values this value will get passed to a function where we will get the `length` of options in select-box and then use this under loop to disabled options from select-box .

**Demo Code** :

```js
function proses_stok() {
  var produk_stock = document.getElementById("produk_size").value;
  document.getElementById("produk_stok").value = produk_stock;
  //if value is small
  if (produk_stock == "stok_s") {
    disable_values(15); //disable from
  } else if (produk_stock == "stok_m") {
    disable_values(20); //disable from

  } else {
    //enable all options
    $("#produk_stok option").prop('disabled', false);
  }

}


function disable_values(start) {
  var s = document.getElementById("produk_stok");
  var end = s.options.length; //getting length of option
  //first enabled all options
  $("#produk_stok option").prop('disabled', false);
  //loop through all options
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    s.options[i].disabled = true; //disabled 
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name=produk_size id=produk_size class=form-control onchange=proses_stok() style=width:95%>
  <option value=0>Select Size:</option>
  <option value=stok_s>s</option>
  <option value=stok_m>m</option>
  <option value=stok_l>L</option>
</select>
<select name="produk_stok" id="produk_stok" class="form-control" style="width:95%">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
```

**Update 1** :

To add options till specific values you can use `for` loop pass the `end` value to it and then append data to some variable and then append this data using `innerHTML` to show under select-box.

**Demo Code** :

```js
function proses_stok() {
  var produk_stock = document.getElementById("produk_size").value;
  //if value is small
  if (produk_stock == "stok_s") {
    disable_values(15); //add till this option
  } else if (produk_stock == "stok_m") {
    disable_values(20); //add till this option

  } else if(produk_stock == "0") {
    document.getElementById("produk_stok").innerHTML = "<option value='0'>0</option>";
  }else{
  //if large size select
  //do somthing ..
  }

}


function disable_values(end) {
  var s = document.getElementById("produk_stok");
 var data="";
  //loop through all options
  for (var i = 1; i <= end; i++) {
  //append options
  data +="<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>";
  }
  //add data to select box
 s.innerHTML= data;
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name=produk_size id=produk_size class=form-control onchange=proses_stok() style=width:95%>
  <option value=0>Select Size:</option>
  <option value=stok_s>s</option>
  <option value=stok_m>m</option>
  <option value=stok_l>L</option>
</select>
<select name="produk_stok" id="produk_stok" class="form-control" style="width:95%">
 <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If to get maximum stok from databases, from this code "disable_values(15); //disable from" i can change "(15)" for "$stok_max(stok_s)" ?

Comment: "stok_s" is column in db

Comment: and the disable value can to change gone? if stok_s just to 15 stok and after 15 like 16-25 is gone or the number just to 15. If i pick stok_m number the option number showing the number 1 to 20

Comment: help plisss  :'D

Comment: so you need to remove all other options ? not disable ?

Comment: yess if i didn't select size the option number just only show 0. and if i'm select size S the option number just showing until 15. and if pick M just showing until 20 the number in option selected

Comment: please check `update 1` and see if that works for you.

Comment: sorry for late respon hehe, thanks i try your code :D

Comment: yeaah really work thanks @Swati im very2 thankss :D

Comment: can you help me in this ask @Swati https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668591/why-the-select-option-didnt-showing-number-where-my-product-have-100-199-stock